# Embedded video not playing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, multimedia

I can play video on the youtube website, but I cannot play youtube videos embedded in facebook or other websites. Captchas are also not showing up, I suspect the two problems are really the same problem. This started about a week or two ago.

Comment: No such problems are present when using Chromium. I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"... I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling firefox."

Uninstalling and reinstalling is *mostly* a waste of time for problems with your browser. You should look at these two references:
[Troubleshoot Firefox issues using Safe Mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)
and
[Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

Problems with browsers commonly arise because of

- some extension/plug-in the user installs or removes or which is updated or which stops working after an update to Firefox.
- corruption of some aspect of the user's profile.

To elaborate, whether an add-on or plug-in is responsible for your problem, a "safe mode" is available and its usage is detailed in the **first link**.
A corruption of some file, a relatively rare situation, can be deduced by using a different profile as described in the **second link**.
Note that backing up your valuable data such as bookmarks is a must.

Comment: Disabling Google Disconnect 2.4.2 add-on. This is not really the perfect solution since I am now without Google Disconnect. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: I don't use it but from what I read the extension blocks trackers. This _can_ be disruptive as you are seeing. If the extension provides you an interactive interface that shows the trackers it blocks, you could, perhaps, pick and choose which ones to block and which to allow.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the culprit was the Google Disconnect 2.4.2 add-on. Disabling it fixes the problem. I am using Firefox 17.0.1.